# PHP functions which make use of wrappers

Tags: php, wrapper

I am in the process of upgrading a PHP code base to be able to run on PHP5.3+ and I need a list of functions that make use of wrappers.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

This page mentions; fopen(), copy(), file_exists() and filesize(). I know for a fact that there are other functions; file_get_contents(), file() and others.

Does anyone has a complete list? Or perhaps an easy way to "grep" through a directory to look for functions using wrappers?

Comment: @ninuhadida - The list most likely would be quite long. I can think of "include", "require", "require_once", "include_once", "readfile", "file", "virtual", all of the "imagecreatefrom...", "DomDocument::loadXMLFile", "Dom::Document::loadHTMLFile", etc. So many of the function rely on the use of filenames/urls. **The real question here is why would you want a complete list?**

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to create such a list because almost every function/method that supports filenames supports stream wrappers, including those in extensions. You cannot really `grep` for all functions using wrappers either because the URLs may be the result from expressions or variables. The best you can do is probably to `grep` for all URLs in a directory.

Comment: @Francois - some wrappers have changed functionality, eg. /dev/stdin needs to be changed to php://stdin. As long as I have a list of functions I can handle it with grep and other tools.

Comment: I thought about just running the application on newer version and check the error logs, but they can easily be suppressed with @ in front of the invocation.

Comment: @ninuhadida - Why can't you search your projects using grep /dev/stdin and the others you're aware have changed? Looking at [Backward Incompatible Changes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php) for instance, the only one mentioned (and in the comments might I add) is /dev/stdin.

Comment: @ninuhadida - since when was /dev/stdin a wrapper and not a device? Also "It is recommended that you simply use the constants STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR instead of manually opening streams using these wrappers"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

grep the php source for `php_stream_open_wrapper_ex` calls, which should give the `PHP_FUNCTION`s that directly interact with wrappers.

A rough and probably partially wrong list (`-B 100` is not exact):

```
$ find . -name '*.c'| xargs grep -B 100 php_stream_open_wrapper_ex| grep PHP_FUNCTION
./ext/standard/url.c-PHP_FUNCTION(rawurlencode)
./ext/standard/url.c-PHP_FUNCTION(rawurldecode)
./ext/standard/url.c-PHP_FUNCTION(get_headers)
./ext/standard/file.c-PHP_FUNCTION(file_get_contents)
./ext/standard/file.c-PHP_FUNCTION(file_put_contents)
./ext/standard/file.c-PHP_FUNCTION(file)
./ext/standard/file.c-PHP_FUNCTION(tempnam)
./ext/standard/file.c-PHP_FUNCTION(mkdir)
./ext/standard/file.c-PHP_FUNCTION(rmdir)
./ext/standard/file.c-PHP_FUNCTION(readfile)
./ext/oci8/oci8_interface.c-PHP_FUNCTION(oci_lob_export)
./ext/hash/hash.c-PHP_FUNCTION(hash)
./ext/hash/hash.c-PHP_FUNCTION(hash_file)
./ext/hash/hash.c-PHP_FUNCTION(hash_update)
./ext/hash/hash.c-PHP_FUNCTION(hash_update_stream)
./ext/hash/hash.c-PHP_FUNCTION(hash_update_file)
```